# How to grant full rights in smb.conf for subnet?

Tags: samba, permissions, write

I have following smb.conf: http://pastebin.com/gCchZQvC

Situation is that when I'm mapping my shares I need to login using my credentials to have ability to create directories and files. When I'm using applications ment to use the share as a write folder I land with write permission denied error. Is there any way to setup smb, so each pc from subnet 192.168.0.0/24 have anonymous read/write access without needing to authenticate? I think that's the issue why I'm landing with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to use `guest account` config option. It determines which local *nix account will be used for guest access.

Try something like this:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = DareFreeBSD 
   security = share 
   hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0/24
   load printers = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   dns proxy = no 

* * * * *

[music]
   comment = Music Share
   path = /media/music
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest account = musicuser
   guest only = yes
[downloads]
   comment = torrent downloads
   path = /home/rtorrent/download
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest account = rtorrent
   guest only = yes

* * * * *
```

More info - in appropriate [samba documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html).

Comment: You're welcome! :)